# X509 certificate creation issuer values

Tags: email, openssl, certificate, x509

I'm creating a X509 certificate using OpenSSL and objective-c.
I want to add some values corresponding to the user which creates the cert. Currently I'm adding `Country`, `Common Name`, `Organization`, `Locality` and `Organization Unit`. For each value a corrseponding key is needed. For example Country is "C", common name is "CN", locality is "L" and so on...
Now I want to add the users email address to the certificate but I can't find the key for it and the OpenSSL docu doesn't mention this anywhere.

I'm adding the values this way:

```
X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(name,"C",
                           MBSTRING_ASC, "AT", -1, -1, 0);
```

I've tried "E", "EA", "Email" for setting the users email address but didn't succeed.

Does anyone know the key to set the email value in issuer name and subject name of a X509 certificate using OpenSSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509 you appear to need to use "CA/emailAddress" as the key...

Comment: Nope. :-/ I guess the keys are only used by OpenSSL to identify a certain value and `CA/emailAddress` doesn't work. The keys are almost just one or two chars.

Answer (score 2):

It was just `emailAddress`.

Here are some others:

```
C=US, 
ST=State or Province, 
L=locality name, 
O=orhanization name, 
OU=org unit, 
CN=common name,
emailAddress=bob@example.com,
serialNumber=1234, 
SN=surname, 
GN=given name, 
GN=name given
```